# Pointer Issues

Tags: c++, pointers

Anyone know how to store pointers in a multi-dimensional array? I think that might be the problem that i am having in main:

```
// main.cpp
#ifdef  _DEBUG
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#endif
#include "Word.h"
using namespace std;

const int WORD_SZ = 100;
Word** g_wordArray;
int g_arrSz;

static char filePath[ FILE_PATH_SZ ] = {};
void FreeWordArray();

int main( const int argc, const char **argv )
{
    int 
        wrdCount = 0;
    char 
        usrMenuOption     = 0,
        getFirstLetter    = 0,
        tmpArray[WORD_SZ] = {},
        *getWord = new char;
    string 
        str, 
        str2;
    ifstream 
        inFile, 
        inFile2;
    do 
    {
        cout << "Please make a selection: \n\
a) Read a text file\n\
b) Remove words starting with letter\n\
c) Print words to console\n\
d) Quit\n";
        cin  >> usrMenuOption;
        switch( usrMenuOption )
        {
        case'A':
        case'a':
            cout << "Enter a file name: ";
            cin.sync();
            cin  >> filePath;
            inFile.open( filePath );
            if ( !inFile ) return -1;
            inFile >> tmpArray; // prime the eof flag.
            while ( !inFile.eof() )
            {   
                inFile >> tmpArray;
                wrdCount++;
                g_wordArray = new Word *[wrdCount];

            }
        inFile.close();
        inFile2.open( filePath );
        while( !inFile2.eof()  )
        {   
            inFile2 >> tmpArray;
            // supplies the member functions with information from the file
            g_wordArray[wrdCount] = new Word( tmpArray );
            g_wordArray[wrdCount]->GetFirstLetterLower();
            g_wordArray[wrdCount]->GetWord();
        }
        cout << wrdCount << " Words read from the file " << endl;
        inFile2.close();
        break;
        case'B':
        case'b':
        // information not found returning null
                g_wordArray[wrdCount]->GetFirstLetterLower();
        break;
        case'C':
        case'c':
                g_wordArray[wrdCount]->GetWord();
        break;
        case'D':
        case'd':
        cout << "Quit Requested. " << endl;
        break;
        default:
        cout << '"' << usrMenuOption << '"' << " Not Defined! " << endl;
        }

    } while ( usrMenuOption != 'D' && usrMenuOption != 'd' );


#ifdef _DEBUG
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
#endif
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}

void FreeWordArray()
{
    delete[ ] g_wordArray;
    return;
}


// Word.cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // disable warnings for strcpy
#define ARRY_SZ 100
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Word.h"
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

// No paramaters.
// Is this what im missing?
// I just threw it in because of an error.
Word::Word() 
{
}

Word::Word( const char* word )
{
    ptr_ = new char[ strlen( word ) + 1 ];
    strcpy( ptr_, word  ); 
    len_ = strlen( ptr_ );
}

Word::~Word()
{
    delete[ ] ptr_;
    ptr_ = NULL;
    len_ = NULL;
}

char Word::GetFirstLetterLower()
{
    char myChar = tolower( ptr_[0] );
    return myChar;

}

char* Word::GetWord()
{
    Word *objectOne = new Word;
    objectOne->ptr_ = ptr_;
    strcpy( objectOne->ptr_, ptr_ );
    return objectOne->ptr_;
}
```

My Goal is to have all the words read from the file in my `g_wordArray[wrdCount]->SomeFunction()` without being dependent in the file reading loop.

What i've been trying to do:

- In the Implementation File, under the `getFirstLetterLower`: to add the `char *_ptr` private member to a new variable each time. like `someCharVar[0] = firstWord`, `someCharVar[1] = secondWord`...
- Reading the contents of the file into a single varaible. Looping through that varaible in each case that i need.

I like that idea, but haven't figured out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you try to explain exactly what problem you are having - it is not really clear from your question

Comment: ... and what you are trying to do (not the code, but the problem you are trying to solve). There may be another method for all you know!

Answer (score 1):

Please post minimal code which can reproduce your problem. It looks quite hazy right now. I suppose there are a lot of problems with this code

```
        inFile >> tmpArray;     // prime the eof flag.
        while ( !inFile.eof() )
        {       
                inFile >> tmpArray;
                wrdCount++;
                g_wordArray = new Word *[wrdCount];

        }
```

You are leaking memory badly here. What happens to the previously allocated 'g_wordArray'?

Also, when you allocate 'n' elements, you cannot access 'nth' index. The memory footprint spans from 0 - (n-1).

```
g_wordArray[wrdCount]
```

Kindly re-check the code, try to debug and then post minimal code.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you are trying to read in a file and optionally remove some words that start with a particular letter. Here's a short example, ***without even rudimentary error handling***, on how you may achieve the same using STL and some templates:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct starts_with {
    char mC;
    starts_with(char c) : mC(c) {}
    bool operator()(std::string const& s) { return s[ 0 ] == mC; }
};

// uses commandline parameters for input arguments
// usage:
//    ./test.exe "path/to/file" letter
// 
// (assumes the file to be read is the first such parameter
// the character to be checked for is the second parameter)
int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]) {
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> v;
    ifstream fStm(argv[ 1 ]);
    istream_iterator<string> b(fStm), e;

    remove_copy_if(b, e, back_inserter(v), starts_with(argv[ 2 ][ 0 ]));

    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about 'remove_copy_if'.  I'm sure I've used that (for the first time) just this week.  It has the same params as your copy_if.

Comment: yeah, sure. Thanks, I just had this ready for some other purpose ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common anti-pattern for reading a file.
Please note that wrdCount is always going to be one off as you detect the end of file (EOF) while inside the loop while reading the word into tmpArray.

```
inFile >> tmpArray;     // prime the eof flag.
while ( !inFile.eof() )
{       
    inFile >> tmpArray;
    wrdCount++;
    g_wordArray = new Word *[wrdCount];
}
```

Use this instead:

```
/*
 * The result of the >> operator is a reference to a stream.
 *
 * When a stream is used in a boolean context (like a while loop)
 * it has a cast method that automatically returns an object
 * of a type that can be used as a boolean.
 *
 * The value of the boolean will be true if the file is still valid
 * and false if something went wrong (like reading past the end of file).
 *
 * So the loop will NOT be entered when you read past the EOF but will
 * be entered for every valid word that is read from the file.
 */
while ( inFile >> tmpArray )
{       
    wrdCount++;
    g_wordArray = new Word *[wrdCount];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing into your arrays is always wrong:

```
g_wordArray[wrdCount]->GetFirstLetterLower();
```

Here 'wrdCount' is the number of elements in 'g_wordArray' so the resulting 'g_wordArray[wrdCount]' is accessing the element one beyond the end of the array.

Remember that C/C++ arrays are indexed from 0 and thus have valid elements 0 -> (wrdCount -1)

Answer (score 0):

You are leaking memory all over the place.
You should try and use the STL standard containers to handle this type of thing.

```
Word** g_wordArray;
```

This would probably be better represented by:

```
std::vector<Word>  g_wordArray;
```

Then rather than allocating space for the array like this:

```
g_wordArray = new Word *[wrdCount];
-----
g_wordArray.reserve(wrdCount);
```

And lastely adding new elements changes lie this:

```
g_wordArray[wrdCount] = new Word( tmpArray );
g_wordArray[wrdCount]->GetFirstLetterLower();
g_wordArray[wrdCount]->GetWord();

------

g_wordArray.push_back(Word( tmpArray ));
g_wordArray[wrdCount].GetFirstLetterLower();    // Note we use . not ->
g_wordArray[wrdCount].GetWord();
```

Now your code no longer uses any nasty new operators and thus you are not going to leak any memory.

Answer (score -2):

What exactly is your question? Where are you getting an error?

Have you considered making `main()` shorter and putting your work in other functions? This code is very difficult to read.
In addition, the do...while loop really is bad to use, consider switching to a while loop instead. You'll need some sort of boolean value, but it's worth it for readability.